# Android Studio profiling apk on physical device

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, apk, adb

I need to profile a release APK in debug mode inside Android Studio.
When I use an emulator, Android Studio installs the APK and succeed to attach to the debuggable process.

In this particular scenario, I need to use a physical device (to debug network traffic) and  when I try to run the APK on my OnePlus GM1900, the app installs, run (I can use it right away), but android studio can't connect to the remote process.

**Logs**

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.xyz.mr/com.xyz.mr.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.xyz.mr | com.xyz.mr
Waiting for application to come online: com.xyz.mr | com.xyz.mr
........
........
........
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
Timed out waiting for process (com.xyz.mr) to appear on oneplus-gm1900-1234567.
```

Because it's working on the emulator, I'm kind of lost...
Is it because OnePlus did shit ? Or is it a common behavior ?
Thank you so much !

Comment: DId you use the same apk on both emulator & device? Also is the release apk signed by debug certificate ?

Comment: Yes, I use the exact same APK. The release apk is not signed with a debug certificate.

Comment: I would try to start the app with debug enabled: `am start -D -n`